# Alamofire general request

Tags: swift, request, alamofire

Could you help me please with this

I'm trying to pull data from API using Alamofire. Is it possible to pull simple data like ["title"] and Image in the same request and populate it in table view?

Here's my code:

```
Alamofire.request(baseURL).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let value = response.result.value{
                let json = JSON(value)
                json.forEach({ (temp) in
                    let title = temp.1["title"].stringValue
                    let run = temp.1["run"].stringValue
                    let image = temp.1["thumb"].stringValue
                    let newmodel = Schedule(title: title, run: run, image: image)
                    self.scheduleArray.append(newmodel)
                })

            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Is it possible to pull simple data like"* - Yes, anything a HTTP server can produce, you can consume - which raises the questions over, what is the server responding with?  You seem to trying to parse some JSON, is the server returning a JSON response?  You question is to general and doesn't point to a specific problem or issue. Were you using a previous approach (`URLSession`?) which was working and this isn't?  What URL are you communicating with? What are the inputs and expected outputs? Are you having trouble parsing the result or populating the table?

Comment: Oh no, I don't have problem with populating data. I just wanted to write 1 Alamofire request for simple objects and image data as well

Comment: So you have, two requests to make that return different data sets and you want to some how combine them?

Comment: Yes, something like 

Alamofire.request(baseURL).response { (response, error, data) in

Comment: This might be beyond the scope of your intention, but I'd consider looking something like "PromiseKit" or "Hydra", which would manage the execution of two async operations and a much more elegant way, other then using a bunch of semaphores and other locking/notification mechanisms ... just saying

Comment: Sounds good, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the base data at first and after that get every image with single request

get base data with this code :

```
 func POSTWithLoad(urlString: String,paramaters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil,success:@escaping (_ responseObject: AnyObject?) -> Void ,failure: @escaping (_ error: String?) -> Void ) {

 Alamofire.request(baseUrlDev+urlString, method: .post, parameters:paramaters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (responseData) in

            if (responseData.result.error == nil && responseData.result.isSuccess == true) {

            //success

             success(responseData)

            } else {

            //fauiler

            failure("UnKnowen Data")

            }

     })
}
```

and use this for getImage :

```
func getImage(link : String , completion : @escaping (_ imageWithLink : (link : String,image : UIImage)) -> Void){
    var image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: link.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("errorLoadIamge : "+link)
            //completion(image)
            print(error)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            let mimage = UIImage(data: data!)
            if(mimage != nil){
                image = mimage!
                completion((link : link , image : image))
                print("successLoadIamge : "+link)
                return
            }
        })

    }).resume()
}
```

then can use it in your ViewContoller like this :

```
    let products : [Product] = []
    let productImages : [String] = []

POSTWithLoad(urlString: "YApiLink" , paramaters: requestParameters as [String : AnyObject]?, success: { (successObject) in

            products = Mapper<Product>().mapArray(JSONObject : successObject)
            productsImages = []
            print(successObject)

        }, failure :{ (failureObject) in

            print(failureObject)

        }
        )


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let product = products[indexPath.row]   
     let cell =  YourTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell

        if let imageAndLink = productsImages.first(where: { $0.link == cell.product?.productImage})
        {cell.pImage?.image = imageAndLink.image}
        else{ cell.pImage.image =  UIImage(named: "placeholder")
            getImage(link: cell.product?.productImage ?? "", completion: {(newImage) in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if self.productsImages.first(where: { $0.link == newImage.link}) == nil
                    {
                        self.productsImages.append(ProductImage(link : newImage.link , image : newImage.image) )
                    }
                    if cell.product?.productImage == newImage.link{
                        cell.pImage.image = newImage.image
                    }
                }

            })
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much